# Reason for different byte[] size of RSAEngine.processBlock

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

What could be the reason/s for different sized byte[] returned from processBlock method in RSAEngine (bcprovjdk16-1.45.jar) class. (127 in one case and 128 in the other on two different machines running the same version of java, [1.7, 64 bit] and using the same public keys for encryption and private keys for decryption and for the same data to be decrypted.

Comment: This is probably the padding scheme. Share some code, otherwise I don't think you can be helped without guessing too much.

Comment: Dunno, but together with a colleague I discovered a mistake in the DH procedures in Bouncy Castle before where they forgot to implement the I2OSP function correctly (that's the integer to octet string primitive), where the integer is formatted as a big endian, unsigned, left padded octet string at the same size of the key. Maybe this is the same kind of issue.

Comment: Darn, cannot create a connection to the FTP download page for previous releases.

Comment: @owlstead: old stuff also seems to be [here](http://polydistortion.net/bc/download/).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if I look at the source code then you can indeed end up with less bytes if the input is not of the same size or if the input has bytes set to zero in front. This should however only be true if you use raw/textbook RSA - i.e. RSA with a padding mode applied to the plaintext. Textbook RSA should not directly be used to encrypt messages (that may have any content).

To solve this, use a padding mode such as PSS or PKCS#1 v1.5, possibly combined with AES for a hybrid cryptosystem.